# How can I design a PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design

I need to make a PCB from this circuit.

Any tips on how to design a PCB, any software to recommend?

[image: This is the sketch]

Comment: If you haven't learned any PCB design automation tool, it will take you much time to learn before you can actually design one.

Comment: Pick a program, Kicad is free and apparently more than usable. Expect a learning curve. Learn a bit about layout (eg. route some good power connections first). Maybe add a Schottky diode in the power circuit so momentary reversed power (as is quite likely with a 9V battery) doesn't [cause permanent damage](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=516737.0).

Comment: Unless your goal is to learn how to design PCBs and the associated tools, you could easily build something as relatively uncomplicated as this on a solderable breadboard in a size of your choice.

Comment: @Felipe:  I second the suggestion to use [KiCAD.](https://kicad-pcb.org/)

Comment: @Felipe Are you intending to use an Arduino Nano as a module, or do you want to put the ATmega328P IC on your own circuit board?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Unfortunately "any tips?" is not really specific enough to fit the intended mission of stack exchange sites.  And we don't really need another page of opinions arguing the virtues of people's variously preferred software packages.  As already pointed out, unless you're making a lot of these it makes more sense to wire it up on a prototype board by hand.  If you have a singular, specific question which can have a *deterministic* answer that is not simply a matter of personal opinion, that could fit here.

Comment: I've used KiCAD with great success by following a tutorial on YouTube and having no prior PCB design experience.

Comment: It's always good to mention what did you look into when you tried to explore pcb design online.

Answer (score 2):

1. Draw a proper circuit diagram.
2. Sketch out an appropriately sized board (one that will hold all of your parts and leave enough room for connectors and traces.)
3. Place parts on the PCB and arrange them so as to minimize crossed traces.
4. Make sure the parts will physically fit around each other as you have placed them.
5. Route traces to connect your parts and connectors.

Any PCB software worth using will have a schematic designer and a PCB designer.  Both parts work together to help you make a PCB that matches your circuit.

The PCB designer reads the schematic file and therefore knows which pins on which parts must be connected together.  It will show you this with the "rat's nest" lines.

You use the rat's nest to help lay out the parts.  Crossed lines in the rat's nest will be crossed traces when you go to routing things.

Place the parts, then move and rotate them until the rat's nest is as simple as you can get it.

Route the traces as indicated by the rat's nest.  Each completed trace causes the corresponding rat's nest line to disappear.  When all of the rat's nest lines are gone, your board is complete.

---

The above will get you a PCB that is a replacement for your wired circuit.

It will **not** produce a good PCB.

There are many things that go into making a good layout - way too many things to go into here.

Make a first board, get it working.  You'll learn about PCBs and electronics as you make and build it.

- Look up things (terms) you don't understand in the software.
- Use written tutorials to learn how to use your PCB design software.
- Ask questions here (the site, not this question) about things you can't figure out.

---

I recommend [KiCAD](https://www.kicad.org/) for hobbyist use.  It is a very capable program without the artificial limits that the "free" or "student" versions of commercial programs have.

KiCAD isn't as friendly as things like Fritzing or the online designers, but it will get you much further before you hit the limits of its abilities.

Answer (score 0):

PCB design is extremely broad topic. Just transferring connection from a breadboard to PCB is easy but Stackup selection, signal integrity, Design for testing, design for manufacturing and certification is completely different thing.

There is no one book to cover all of those aspects.

Only answer anybody can give you here is which options you have for tools. Some of the tools are:
CircuitMaker (Free)
KiCad (Free)
Altium
Cadence Allegro
Eagle
PADS

Whichever tool you select it will take time to get familiar with all the menus, options and shortcuts.

Comment: For a beginner level, all those things you just mentioned aren't really important. S/he can learn about them later.

Comment: yeah like mentioned Just transferring connection from a breadboard to PCB is easy

Answer (score 0):

EasyEDA is a free, web-based service for circuit design that is oriented towards beginners that want to design a circuit board without necessarily having a lot of design experience or understanding of traditional EDA tools:

https://easyeda.com/

They also partner with board houses, which simplifies ordering if you are not familiar with the process.  While I prefer KiCAD, for your purposes EasyEDA may be a better choice.

There are a lot of great videos on YouTube showing design of basic circuits using it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdcnkaAoDTE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpKK6o4ffts (older but still good)

Take a look and see if this would work for you.  Otherwise, KiCAD is a great choice, but there is a learning curve.